# How can I add the "defer" attribute in a line of code in yattag?

Tags: python, yattag

I'm trying to write this html line of code:

```html
<script defer src="/js/table_2.js"></script>
```

in yattag format as follows:

```
doc.asis("script", defer="defer",src="/js/table_2.js")
```

but I get an error in the defer attribute, does somebody know how to include this attribute in a yattag line of code?

Comment: what error ? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes that don't have a value can be passed as simple strings:

```
with tag("script", "defer", src="js/table_2.js"):
    pass
```

There's an example like this at the end of the paragraph about the `tag` method: https://www.yattag.org/#the-tag-method

Answer (score 0):

Based on source code for [asis()](https://github.com/leforestier/yattag/blob/master/yattag/simpledoc.py#L223) it needs `string with HTML` and it will use it as-is

```
doc.asis('<script defer src="/js/table_2.js"></script>')
```

---

**EDIT:**

[Documentation](https://www.yattag.org/) in point `2. Appending strings "as is"` also uses full string with HTML

```
doc.asis('<!DOCTYPE html>')
```